NextJS microfrontend with webpack, filename issue
**My remote is on port 3001, and host on port 3000, notice I've index.tsx and _app.js, _document.js
I'm using NextJS page routing and this is my remote app's webpack config in next.config.js
trailingSlash: true,
 webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.output.publicPath = "http://localhost:3001/_next/static/";
      config.plugins.push(
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          name: "webapp",
          filename: "static/remoteEntry.js",
          exposes: {
            "./Homepage": "./pages/index.tsx", 
            "./Document": "./pages/_document", 
            "./App": "./pages/_app", 
          },

          shared: // my shared module
        })
      );
    }

    return config;
  },

However in my host app, instead of accessing http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/index, it accesses the following route
http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages_index_tsx.js My / and . are being replaced by _
Now I'm able to access remoteEntry.js and the apps are running fine individually, but my host is unable to load remote app component because of this. Please let me know, how can I fix this
I've tried all chatGPT solutions and still issue persists
My host is accessing as
module.exports = {
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          name: "container",
          remotes: {
            webapp:
              "webapp@http://localhost:3001/_next/static/remoteEntry.js", 
           },
          shared: //shared file
        })
      );
    }

    return config;
  },
};

